# How to reset static IP address back to DHCP for ethernet

Tags: adb, dhcp, ip-address

I have setup a static ip address for `eth0` with adb command `ip addr add $ipAddress dev eth0` plus other commands to set the `netmask`, `route` and dns values.

My question is how to I go back to a non static IP address

I tried doing `ifconfig eth0 dhcp` but I get an error in adb saying

> ifconfig: bad argument 'dhcp'

Right now the only way I can reset everything is if I reboot the device since the changes dont persist.

How can I reset them without a reboot?

Comment: If Android runs DHCP client on Ethernet interface, it's not removed by adding a static IP address to the interface. However you also changed the routing table and DNS. It means you need to force the DHCP client for a lease renewal. But Android's DHCP client runs in Java framework and there is no straightforward method to communicate with it (some `service` calls may work but I never tested). Also, usually there's no GUI settings to turn Ethernet on/off like WiFi and Mobile Data. So the simple approach is to replug the Ethernet cable. Or restart the device.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I came across `ifconfig eth0 default` that seems to reset everything like it would on a reboot all routes, netmasks and dns values appear to be reset. Any input on using that command?

Answer (score 1):

Solution without root privileges:

- Disable WiFi
- Run:

  ```
   adb shell settings put global wifi_connected_mac_randomization_enabled 1
  ```
- Enable WiFi and connect to your network

You should have a new IP.

Comment: I have root privileges

Comment: It works also if you have root privileges.

Comment: /system/bin/sh: put: not found

Comment: @CSQGB `settings` was missing in the command

Comment: @android:/data/local # put global wifi_connected_mac_randomization_enabled 1
/system/bin/sh: put: not found